# "Localhost didnt send any data" Docker error (React + Spring)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, docker, nginx

I want to containerize my application using Docker. The app consists of two microservices "User" and "Device" created using Spring, and a frontend using React. After several hours, I got all the docker images to work and the back-end connected to the database. This is how it looks in docker:
[Docker Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drzgQ.png).

The only error I get is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when accessing localhost:3000 on the browser. There are no error messages in the docker.

My React docker file:

```
    FROM node:16-alpine  
    WORKDIR /app  
    COPY package\*.json ./  
    RUN npm install  
    COPY . .  
    RUN npm run build  
    EXPOSE 80  
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

These are the images and ports from the docker-compose file:

```
    spring-demo1:  
    image: user-service  
    ports:  
    "8081:8081"  
    spring-demo2:  
    image: device-service  
    ports:  
    "8080:8080"  
    frontend:  
    image: frontend-service  
    ports:  
    "3000:80"
```

I have also tried using ngnx to run the server:

```
    FROM nginx:alpine  
    COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  
    EXPOSE 80  
    #CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And I can get the server to run the nginx index page, but I didnt manage to get the app to run my index.html file.

```
    http {  
    server {  
        listen 80;
            location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
            }  
            location /spring-demo1/ {
                proxy_pass http://spring-demo1:8081/;
            }   
            location /spring-demo2/ {
                proxy_pass http://spring-demo2:8080/;
            }
        }
    }
```

As a project structure: my docker-compose file is at the highest level and nginx.conf is in the "front-end" project

1. root
   docker-compose
2. user-micro
   dockerfile
3. device-micro
   dockerfile
4. front-end
   dockerfile
   nginx.conf

I have searched a lot for a solution, but I could not get anything to work... If anyone has any idea on what to change, please tell me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error messages (if any) or a clearer description of the problem, and to correct the typographical errors in the code blocks (backslashes in the Dockerfile, indentation in the Compose file).  From what you've written here it's not clear what's actually going wrong.

Comment: I dont have any error in the docker. The only error is "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on the browser, when accessing localhost:3000... I will edit it now, sorry for the backslashes, I missed them